# A difficult integral

Tags: stochastic-calculus, calculus-of-variations

Is there any analytical result on the following integral?
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-x^2}}{1+e^{-(x-\mu)}}dx$$
Thanks a lot!

Comment: This is a case of the [Mordell integral](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MordellIntegral.html). You might find some information in [one of my questions at Mathematica.se](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/97750/more-efficient-method-to-compute-moments-of-the-johnson-s-b-distribution).

Comment: I am actually curious in what context did you encounter it. Could you share some of your motivation?

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე Thanks for the information. In the linear-nonlinear model of signal process of a single neuron, that integral appears very often. So far, many computation results came out. However, I wanna try to get some analytical results.

Answer (score 4):

The integral is a special case of what is called Gauss–Fermi function in semiconductor physics. In general, it cannot be calculated analytically. However some semi-analytical approximations do exist. See, for example, http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10825-014-0615-7 (Analytical evaluation of charge carrier density of organic materials with Gauss density of states, by T. Mehmetoğlu) and references therein.

Answer (score 4):

Maple can evaluate this integral for integer and half-integer values of $\mu$. The values seem have a nice pattern.  Let the value of the integral be $F(\mu)$.  Then $F(0)= \frac12\sqrt\pi$ and for integer $\mu$ with $1\le\mu\le 30$, 
$$ F(\mu) = - \sqrt\pi\,e^{-\mu^2} \biggl(\frac12 + \sum_{i=1}^{2\mu-1} (-1)^i e^{i^2/4}\Biggr).$$
There's also an obvious symmetry that gives $F(-\mu)+F(\mu)=\sqrt\pi$.

For half-integers, the empirical pattern is $F(\mu+\frac12)=F(-\mu)e^{-\mu-1/4}$ (checked for lots of integer $\mu$).

I assume these are all easy to prove but I'll leave that for someone else.